# Counting pairs of edges in a random graph

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G(n,p)$ be a random graph on $n$ vertices where edges are chosen independently with probability $p$. I want to count the expected number of pairs of edges in this graph.

To my understanding, if we choose edges with probability $p$, then the expected number of edges is $p\binom{n}{2}$ since there are the total of $\binom{n}{2}$ possible edges. Since we consider the expected number of pairs of edges, this quantity would then be $(p\binom{n}{2})^2$. Am I correct in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

For all possible pairs of edges, both edges are in the random graph with probability $p^2$. The number of possible edges is $n_e=\binom{n}{2}$, and the number of possible pairs of edges is $n_p=\binom{n_e}{2}$

By linearity of expectation, $$E=p^2\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{2}$$